# How to drag multiple layouts in a layout graphically in Qt Designer?

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I'm using Qt Designer to create a graphic interface, but i am struggling to do a basic operation.

I want to create a vertical layout in which there are 2 (or more) horizontals layouts. But if I try to grab my horizontal layouts to put them in the vertical one, the first horizontal layout ends up taking all the space in vertical layout, so i can't add the second one other than inside the first hozitontal layout.

I end up with Horizontal layout 1 in Horizontal layout 2 in Vertical layout which is not what i want

here is the picture or what i get :
[image]

VS what i want :
[image]

I tried to do it through the Tree object at the right, but it seems we can't drag and drop objets there nor can i copy and paste it to change the ancestor. Is there any way to do it other than editing the XML file ?

Answer (score 0):

One fewer horizontal layout (spacers added for clarity):
[image]

Comment: Sorry, maybe i was not very clear in my question but the point was to add them in another vertical layout, not in the main QWidget. However i think i found the solution, it was to select both of my horizontal layout before dragging them in my vertical layout

Answer (score 0):

### Cause

Qt Designer sets the margins of the newly added layouts to `0, 0, 0, 0`, so it is impossible to target with the mouse a 0px-wide area when you try to add something to the layout.

### Solution

Change the margins of the layout temporarily to something, which is comfortable for you to hit with the mouse. Then you can easily drag and drop new items to this layout. Later you could change the margins back to 0.